# Where is the documentation for Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook

Could someone help me find the documentation for the PHP Facebook SDK? I can't understand where I can see which methods I can invoke on e.g. the Facebook application instance `$facebook`.

Comment: have you tried Google? It's a search engine that knows everything! http://www.google.com/?q=facebook%20sdk%20php

Comment: @Mihai: Yes I have smartass. Start reading the questions entirely and you will see that it was not what I was looking after.

Comment: :) as there is NO exact documentation for the SDK as it changes every single week, you have to "read" the sdk ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook tends to document the API, not the SDK. So you need to look at the Graph API documentation. The PHP SDK used to have many, many more functions in it, and more documentation. The latest iteration is considerably smaller, thus not documented well. Many times Facebook puts PHP examples in the documentation for the Graph API. So if you lookup documentation for some functionality, you may find PHP example. For example, authentication.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

I've actually migrated a lot of my functionality to javascript. The javascript SDK is much better documented. Also, I think it creates a much better user experience since you don't need to use URL redirects to accomplish things. The javascript SDK also helped me determine what is possible with the PHP SDK.

I've been developing Facebook apps for about 5 years now, using PHP. There is no magical place for documentation you haven't found.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is almost non-existant you generally have to piece together what you can from the examples on [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/) & [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk), [online tutorials](http://www.google.ie/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=facebook+php+sdk+tutorial) and asking specific questions here on SO.

Most would have learned of the methods available on a Facebook instance by examining the class source for the public methods.
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/src